# cant enter to grub

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I´m having troubles with my hp 1000 laptop. Is an old laptop but i´ve managed to make an dual-boot back in the day. the problem is that now i installed windows 10 first and then i installed ubuntu 19.04, both in uefi mode and with secure mode enabled on my bios.

After the installation of ubuntu was finished i had the same problem over and over again: I cant get to GRUB on the start. this laptop dont have the option to change the boot order from bios what i can only do is press f9 to select the boot option, but i need it to bee automatic.

When i dont press anything i just go to windows 10. so i installed boot-repair and done the usual things i.e i just made the recommended config on boot-repair and then on windows 10 i entered the bcdedit command to change the bootmgr. it still does the same thing on booting without pressing anything it just goes straight to windows 10.

i have posted the results of boot-repair to pastebin and here is the link to it.
http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/kBNvNJztDV/

what can i do?

Comment: After your response I double checked and it has the latest bios by HP page of drivers but I couldn't find the part of changing the boot order. Is a computer from 2013

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I came trough a solution to my problem if are people having the same problem. What is probably the issue is that secure boot is having trouble with the Ubuntu installation all I did was disable secure boot and then enable legacy support and that was it. Anyway thanks for the help